# How to maintain position when using position absolute

Tags: css, dropdown, css-position

I'm trying to build a `custom DropDown` List. I use position relative for the container and absolute for the content. the problem is the `hr` under my element doesn't follow my dropdown position.

here is my code snippet

```js
document.querySelector(".ddl").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let selectedOption = document.querySelector('.dllList>data[selected]');
  if (e.target.tagName == "DATA") {
    if (selectedOption != null) {
      selectedOption.removeAttribute('selected');
    }
    e.target.setAttribute('selected', '');
    document.querySelector(".ddlBtn").innerText = e.target.innerText;
    document.querySelector(".ddl").open = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.ddlWrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.ddl {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0;
  width: 230px;
  /* pointer-events: none;  prevents click events */
  user-select: none;
  /* prevents text selection */
}

.ddl[open] {
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
}

.ddl>summary {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: -0.5em -0.5em 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ddl>summary:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

details[open] summary {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}


/********************************************************************* ul li */

.dllList {
  min-height: 5opx;
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.dllList>data {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.dllList>data:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.dllList>data[selected] {
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
}

.dllList>data:hover:not([selected]) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/*********************************** Ctrl Buttons */

.editIco {
  float: right;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='balck' class='bi bi-pencil-square' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z'/%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.editIco:hover {
  /*fill: #94d31b; */
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='red' class='bi bi-pencil-square' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z'/%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.deleteIco {
  float: right;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='black' class='bi bi-trash3' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M6.5 1h3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1H6v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5ZM11 2.5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 0h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 5 1.5v1H2.506a.58.58 0 0 0-.01 0H1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h.538l.853 10.66A2 2 0 0 0 4.885 16h6.23a2 2 0 0 0 1.994-1.84l.853-10.66h.538a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-.995a.59.59 0 0 0-.01 0H11Zm1.958 1-.846 10.58a1 1 0 0 1-.997.92h-6.23a1 1 0 0 1-.997-.92L3.042 3.5h9.916Zm-7.487 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .528.47l.5 8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.998.06L5 5.03a.5.5 0 0 1 .47-.53Zm5.058 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .47.53l-.5 8.5a.5.5 0 1 1-.998-.06l.5-8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .528-.47ZM8 4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.deleteIco:hover {
  /*fill: #94d31b; */
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='red' class='bi bi-trash3' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M6.5 1h3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1H6v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5ZM11 2.5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 0h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 5 1.5v1H2.506a.58.58 0 0 0-.01 0H1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h.538l.853 10.66A2 2 0 0 0 4.885 16h6.23a2 2 0 0 0 1.994-1.84l.853-10.66h.538a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-.995a.59.59 0 0 0-.01 0H11Zm1.958 1-.846 10.58a1 1 0 0 1-.997.92h-6.23a1 1 0 0 1-.997-.92L3.042 3.5h9.916Zm-7.487 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .528.47l.5 8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.998.06L5 5.03a.5.5 0 0 1 .47-.53Zm5.058 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .47.53l-.5 8.5a.5.5 0 1 1-.998-.06l.5-8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .528-.47ZM8 4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.addIco {
  float: right;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='balck' class='bi bi-plus-circle' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.addIco:hover {
  /*fill: #94d31b; */
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='red' class='bi bi-plus-circle' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}


/***************************************** Scrolling Style */


/* width */

.dllList::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}


/* Track */

.dllList::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Handle */

.dllList::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}


/* Handle on hover */

.dllList::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<span class="ddlWrapper">
<details class="ddl">
  <summary>
    <span class="ddlBtn">please Select</span>
</summary>
<div class="dllList">
  <data value="1"> Mohamed </data>
  <data value="2"> Ahmed </data>
  <data value="3"> Ali </data>
  <data value="4"> Mostafa </data>
  <data value="5"> Khaled </data>
  <data value="6"> Yusof </data>
  <data value="7"> Omran </data>
  <data value="8"> Ramy </data>
  <data value="9"> Samy </data>
  <data value="10"> Eslam </data>
</div>
</details>
</span>

<hr />
```

As it's obvious that the `<hr />` element is not in the right place in relation to my custom dropdown list.

I guess I'm missing something in my CSS.

Comment: I'm not clear where you want the hr to appear. Could you explain a bit more.

Comment: @AHaworth it should be under the dropdown. as it is obvious in html hr next to dropdown.

Comment: Just a comment - details cannot be a child of span.

Comment: But you've made the dropdown position absolute so it doesn't have any affect on following elements' positioning (in this case, the hr element).

Comment: @AHaworth mmmmm I didn't know that. So, what is the solution from your point. I have the container position relative `.ddlWrapper{ position: relative;}` what should I do more?

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.

When an element is set with `position: absolute`, the element is no longer in the normal document flow. You can think of that element as kind of hovering over the whole HTML page and won't interact with other elements but only the nearest ancestor which has a position set to either `relative` or `absolute`.

As for your dropdown, the `absolute` will create that hovering effect which is a very common pattern in web design (However, on smaller devices or screen sizes, stacked menus are often used instead, since it's scrollable)

So there's no need to use `absolute` positioning for your dropdown. If you want that `<hr />` element to follow right after the dropdown, you can simply remove all positioning rules from your dropdown:

```js
document.querySelector(".ddl").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let selectedOption = document.querySelector('.dllList>data[selected]');
  if (e.target.tagName == "DATA") {
    if (selectedOption != null) {
      selectedOption.removeAttribute('selected');
    }
    e.target.setAttribute('selected', '');
    document.querySelector(".ddlBtn").innerText = e.target.innerText;
    document.querySelector(".ddl").open = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.ddlWrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 50px;
}

.ddl {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0;
  width: 230px;
  /* pointer-events: none;  prevents click events */
  user-select: none;
  /* prevents text selection */
}

.ddl[open] {
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
}

.ddl>summary {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: -0.5em -0.5em 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ddl>summary:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

details[open] summary {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}


/********************************************************************* ul li */

.dllList {
  min-height: 5opx;
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.dllList>data {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.dllList>data:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.dllList>data[selected] {
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
}

.dllList>data:hover:not([selected]) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/*********************************** Ctrl Buttons */

.editIco {
  float: right;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='balck' class='bi bi-pencil-square' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z'/%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.editIco:hover {
  /*fill: #94d31b; */
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='red' class='bi bi-pencil-square' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z'/%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.deleteIco {
  float: right;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='black' class='bi bi-trash3' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M6.5 1h3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1H6v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5ZM11 2.5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 0h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 5 1.5v1H2.506a.58.58 0 0 0-.01 0H1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h.538l.853 10.66A2 2 0 0 0 4.885 16h6.23a2 2 0 0 0 1.994-1.84l.853-10.66h.538a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-.995a.59.59 0 0 0-.01 0H11Zm1.958 1-.846 10.58a1 1 0 0 1-.997.92h-6.23a1 1 0 0 1-.997-.92L3.042 3.5h9.916Zm-7.487 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .528.47l.5 8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.998.06L5 5.03a.5.5 0 0 1 .47-.53Zm5.058 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .47.53l-.5 8.5a.5.5 0 1 1-.998-.06l.5-8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .528-.47ZM8 4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.deleteIco:hover {
  /*fill: #94d31b; */
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='red' class='bi bi-trash3' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M6.5 1h3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1H6v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5ZM11 2.5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 0h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 5 1.5v1H2.506a.58.58 0 0 0-.01 0H1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h.538l.853 10.66A2 2 0 0 0 4.885 16h6.23a2 2 0 0 0 1.994-1.84l.853-10.66h.538a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-.995a.59.59 0 0 0-.01 0H11Zm1.958 1-.846 10.58a1 1 0 0 1-.997.92h-6.23a1 1 0 0 1-.997-.92L3.042 3.5h9.916Zm-7.487 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .528.47l.5 8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.998.06L5 5.03a.5.5 0 0 1 .47-.53Zm5.058 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .47.53l-.5 8.5a.5.5 0 1 1-.998-.06l.5-8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .528-.47ZM8 4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.addIco {
  float: right;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='balck' class='bi bi-plus-circle' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.addIco:hover {
  /*fill: #94d31b; */
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='red' class='bi bi-plus-circle' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}


/***************************************** Scrolling Style */


/* width */

.dllList::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}


/* Track */

.dllList::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Handle */

.dllList::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}


/* Handle on hover */

.dllList::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="ddlWrapper">
  <details class="ddl">
    <summary>
      <span class="ddlBtn">please Select</span>
    </summary>
    <div class="dllList">
      <data value="1"> Mohamed </data>
      <data value="2"> Ahmed </data>
      <data value="3"> Ali </data>
      <data value="4"> Mostafa </data>
      <data value="5"> Khaled </data>
      <data value="6"> Yusof </data>
      <data value="7"> Omran </data>
      <data value="8"> Ramy </data>
      <data value="9"> Samy </data>
      <data value="10"> Eslam </data>
    </div>
  </details>
</div>

<hr />
```

Comment: Thanks @Joshua for your effort. but the `hr` still moving down when the dropdown opened. I mean I need to make it `hr` under the dropdown element but in the same time I need the element behavior act like real `select options` to don't push content beneath

Comment: Sorry, I somehow misunderstood your question earlier. I've updated the snippet. Could you give it a look and let me know if it works for you?